# Click to expand not working after using $scope.apply()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This is my Angular app where I am fetching data from firestore
I am using click to expand the data

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {

  if (queryString.length == 0) {
    if (window.location.search.split('?').length > 1) {
        var params = window.location.search.split('?')[1].split('&');
        for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
            var key = params[i].split('=')[0];
            var value = decodeURIComponent(params[i].split('=')[1]);
            queryString[key] = value;
            id=queryString["id"];
        }
    }
  }

  db.collection("Wellness")
  .doc(id)
  .get()
  .then(function(doc) {
    if (doc.exists) {
      $scope.records = doc.data();
    } else {
        dismissDialog();
        // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log("No such document!");
    }

    console.log($scope.records);
    $scope.$apply();

  }).catch(function(error) {
    dismissDialog();
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
  });
```

this is my HTML Code

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
<ul class="accordion accordion-2 accordion--oneopen" style="min-height: 369px;">
                                <li ng-repeat="item in records.details track by $index">
                                    <div class="accordion__title">
                                        <span class="h5">{{item.tittle}}</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="accordion__content">
                                        <span>Your pet will be provided a private, clean and comfortable space which
                                              no other pet can access. Hourly, cleanliness check will be performed.
                                         </span>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>

                            <p>
                                    <label>Select Your City</label>
                                    <select id = "myList">

                                      <option ng-repeat="item in rec.cityNames" value = "{{item.tittle}}">{{item}}</option>

                                    </select>
                                 </p>

                            <style>
                                .collapsible {
                                    background-color: #777;
                                    color: white;
                                    cursor: pointer;
                                    padding: 18px;
                                    width: 100%;
                                    border: none;
                                    text-align: left;
                                    outline: none;
                                    font-size: 15px;
                                }

                                .active, .collapsible:hover {
                                    background-color: #555;
                                }

                                .content {
                                    padding: 0 18px;
                                    display: none;
                                    overflow: hidden;
                                    background-color: #f1f1f1;
                                }
                                </style>


                                <div ng-repeat="item in records.details track by $index">
                                <button class="collapsible">{{item.tittle}}</button>
                                <div class="content">
                                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                                </div>
                                </div>

                                <script>
                                var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
                                var i;

                                for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
                                    coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
                                        this.classList.toggle("active");
                                        var content = this.nextElementSibling;
                                        if (content.style.display === "block") {
                                            content.style.display = "none";
                                        } else {
                                            content.style.display = "block";
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                                </script>


                            </div>
```

*When I am writing a hardcode Data the click to Expand function works but when fetching data from firebase and adding a $scope.apply() then click to expand does not works 
I have tried many possible solutions but not workings please suggest me some solution 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please fix the layout/indentation of your code, this is painful to read.

Comment: Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess about your problem:

You add click listeners with this piece of code:

> ERRONEOUS
>
> ```
> coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
>     this.classList.toggle("active");
>     var content = this.nextElementSibling;
>     if (content.style.display === "block") {
>         content.style.display = "none";
>     } else {
>         content.style.display = "block";
>     }
> });
> ```

This piece of code is executed when the page is loaded, and unfortunately, the DB has not returned the results yet because it is async (that's why it works when you set up mock data manually, they are set up from the beginning). Therefore, there is no `<button class="collapsible">` yet, and there is no click listener set up.

To fix this, it's quite easy, you have to

### INSTEAD use AngularJS `ng-click`.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in records.details track by $index">
    <button class="collapsible" ng-click="onClick($event)">{{item.tittle}}</button>
    <div class="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And remove that `<script>` tag!

In your controller, add your function to the scope:

```
$scope.onClick = function(e) {
    e.target.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = e.target.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.display === "block") {
         content.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        content.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

Here it is.

You just have to know a little bit better AngularJS and use its features ;)

Comment: thanx works like a charm 
actually i am new in angular